# Creating a Chrome Extension to open a link in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a simple chrome extension that when clicked opens a url in a new browser tab. This is what I have for the manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Sprout Social",
    "description": "Shortcut to Sprout Social",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "launch": {
        "web_url": "http://www.sproutsocial.com"
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What link are you talking about? A link on a page? A browserAction button?

Answer (score 14):

Ok, first of all, manifest.json (not jason) has a strict structure, you can't mess with it.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html

You have to create a Browser Action extension, that means your extension will have a button near the tool button.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html

You don't need any popup.html, you can skip that part.
You need to write your background page, many people name it background.html 
This HTML file will have your code, in this form:

```
<html><head><script> your script here (use as many lines as you want)  </script></head>/html>
```

This HTML won't never show up.

And the code can be anything you want, like the code in the other answer:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://www.sproutsocial.com"});
});
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler solution, you do not need HTML.

Add this to **manifest.json**

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon38.png",
    "default_title": "Your title"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

Create the **background.js** file, with this code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "http://www.yoursite.com" });
});
```

Note: I do not add `"permissions": ["tabs"]` in manifest.json since it adds the Permission Warning: "Read your browsing history" and that can be confusing to the user. The extension still works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the method you want to define in your schema is

```
  chrome.tabs.create

 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

      chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {

      });

 });
```